# implementing a SOAP web service with a wrong wsdl

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I am trying to implement a soap ws client in my java application. I have a WSDL file to generate the client stubs. When I implemented the code, I saw that the WSDL file is out of date and I can not get the response as expected in the WSDL. I do not have an option to make the vendor update WSDL.

What are my options to implement the client properly?

Is it possible to fix the WSDL manually or intercept the response before generated codes receive the response?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can always get the most updated WSDL by accessing the URL from the browser. Since you are able to communicate with the server application I assume you have the server application endpoint.

The URL should be simller to the folliwng

```
http[s]://(IP or Domain Name)[:port]/.../...?WSDL
```

Here is an example for a common WSDL online for global weather as an example of how WSDL URL look like

```
http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL
```

***Additional Details:***

You can re-generate the stub classes from WSDL URL directly using many tools like:

**Axis**

[Code Generator Wizard Guide for Eclipse Plug-in](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/wsdl2java-plugin.html)

[Code Generator Tool Guide for Command Line and Ant Task](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html#cmdline)

**Apache CXF**

[Generate a JAX-WS Web Service Client from a WSDL document using Apache CXF](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html)

Comment: the vendor updated the service but did not update the wsdl. That is the problem.